# how to install windows 8 x64 from the dreamspark windows 8 32/64 ISO?

Tags: windows-8, installation, 64-bit

I am a student and I have a Dreamspark account. I have an x64 laptop so I downloaded Windows 8 Professional 32/64 from their site (there was no other version only for x64). After I install the OS, I found that Windows installed on 32 bits. This is not what I want and during the installation I did't see any option for that (a checkbox or something).

My question is: How can I install Windows 8 x64 from a 32/64 ISO downloaded from Dreamspark?

Comment: You will need to talk to the Admin that handles your Dreamspark program to add the product to your school's program.

Answer (score 2):

You can choose which version of Windows 8 you want to download when you click "Start Download" in the DreamSpark website. When the *Secure Download Manager* opens you can choose between the 32-bit version or the 64-bit version to download ;)